# DC Power supply voltage swing when load turns on

Tags: power, ground

Below is flow diagram of my pcb power side, the issue is when relay turn on a 12V 30 watt heater element the voltage drops (or swing) and stay down until load disables. This drop cause issue on my amplifier circuit and I want to know why other regulator dont regulate the voltage back to normal. (I have tried external AC/DC converter with Rigol DL3000 DC load and voltage drops too)

The most interesting is this does happen some time and some time by just turning on and off unit it goes away but mostly is over there.
Note: 5V buck  regulator below is typo
[image]

Below graph shows' the input supply when load turns on and off
[image]

Below graph is 12V buck boost regulator (Different recording)
[image]

External Supply :  RACM230-24SG Output
24V 9.58A 80 ~ 264 VAC, 120 ~ 370 VDC Input

Let me know if I you need more info

Comment: So, what currents are all your supplies designed to supply? That's the one most important info here, and I think you forgot to tell us.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added the external AC dc convertor info

Comment: The data sheet only guarantees +/- 1.0% output accuracy, and load regulation of 0.5%. 0.08V is 0.3% of 24V.

Comment: Why are you using a buck-boost regulator for your 5V supply if the input is already regulated 12 V? buck-boost regulators are less efficient than buck regulators and the boost function doesn't seem to serve any purpose here.

Comment: @Hearth my mistake is just buck regulator

Comment: @nobody that is very good point but why my buck boost regulator drop or 5 v drops too

Comment: @shahreza you've still not told us for how much current your other two supplies, the 12 V and 5 V Buck/boost converters, are designed for

Comment: Can you show the layout? Could be an issue due to current in ground.

Comment: @mmmm sorry the 12v design for max 10A and 5v max 4A

Comment: I don't see any line or load regulation error specs  ,so I don't see any problems with the data shown

Comment: @bobflux The schematic is large I do not know how to attach pdf, image doesnt show values

Comment: It's good practice to isolate your control and instrumentation power from your large loads power as early as possible. They should never be cascaded in series. Change your 5V Buck-Boost to a chip that can handle 40V in and run it directly from the 24V supply or get yourself a different 12-18V buck converter for the control circuits so you can isolate them from the load. You can also run the LT1461 directly from 12V.

Answer (score 0):

Your first graph shows a ~70 mV change on a 24 V supply. That's 0.3% variation. You don't have a vertical scale on your scope plot of the 12V regulator, but if the magnitude of the changes is similar, there's nothing to worry about. Neither your voltage reference nor your amplifier should be bothered by small changes in the supply voltage. Is this a noise issue?

1. Do you have capacitors on the voltage reference and amplifier's supply rails?
2. Are you able to power the 5V regulator directly from the 24V supply? The heater probably draws a lot of current, and switching that will add noise to your power rails.
3. What are the supply currents?

Comment: I agree 0.3% change on 24v is okay my problem this will effect my voltage reference voltage which connect to virtual gnd and cause swing in opamp output. I have capacitor on both input and output of each regulator , voltage reference, and opamp (I even tried 10uf on voltage reference)

Comment: I forgot to add the external supply is rate for 24V 9A

Comment: We're not asking for the current rating, we're asking how much current they're actually drawing. What's the 12V regulator current when the heater is on and when it's off?

Comment: Oh, when is on 2.5A ar 12v

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like the main problem is that you're running the 5V regulator off of the 12V regulator's output. If you do 24V -> 5V, then you'll have a good ground, right?

Comment: The board is 4 layer and one of the layer is only ground. I have to relayout board to power 5v from 24